# Use Include method to show specific fields in a jount table

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working on `RestAPI` and i am trying to use the Include method (include joint table) in Get request by HobbyId to show specific fileds from this table not everything.

Tables: 
User, 
Hobby. 
Joint Table is : HobbyUsers which i want to show only HobbyId and SkillsLevel fiels from this table.

```cs
public async Task<User[]> GetUsersByHobby(int hobbyID)
{
    _logger.LogInformation($"Getting Users for hobby with ID:{hobbyID}");
    IQueryable<User> query =
                  _context.Users
                  .Include(a => a.HobbyUsers.Select(a => new
                      {
                          Id = a.HobbyId,
                          SkillLevel = a.SkillLevel
                      }))
                  .Where(h => h.HobbyUsers.Any(u => u.Hobby.HobbyId == hobbyID))
                  .OrderBy(u => u.HobbyUsers.First().SkillLevel);

    return await query.ToArrayAsync();
}
```

Comment: What should the output look like? You clearly can't return `User`s because they won't have a property to contain the skill levels.

Comment: You might have some luck using the technique outlined in [this article](https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/building-efficient-database-queries-using-entity-framework-core-and-automapper/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **cannot add conditions in the Include method in ef core**, so to filter the fields displayed in the results, you need to `select the whole after the where condition`.

But because you want to remove some fields in the result, then the content returned by the query will not be accepted as `User` type (has been changed to `a custom type`), you need to use **`var`** to receive.

Here is the demo:

```
var query = _context.Users
              .Include(a => a.HobbyUsers)
              .Where(h => h.HobbyUsers.Any(u => u.Hobby.HobbyId == hobbyID))
              .Select(x => new 
              {
                  //here are Users class fields, you can change to what your class has.
                  Id = x.Id,
                  Name = x.Name,
                  HobbyUsers = x.HobbyUsers.Select(a => new 
                  {
                      Id = a.HobbyId,
                      SkillLevel = a.SkillLevel
                  })
              }).OrderBy(u => u.HobbyUsers.First().SkillLevel).ToList();
```